# SharePoint online "Read more" Client Side Rendering for Announcements List (Newsletter view)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, client-side-scripting

Frequent stalker but one of the few times I am posting. I have been trying unsuccessfully to implement Client Side Rendering on a SharePoint online list using the following methods:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151473/how-to-truncate-a-multiline-column-in-a-sharepoint-list-2013

While this is the closest to what I am trying to achieve, it is not exact. I am looking for a way to truncate a multi-line body column displayed in Newsletter view that can be expanded and collapsed using the Read More button or alternatively using a Hover Over option. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[Example view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiI0U.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately when customizing list view via CSR *custom* style (e.g. `Newsletter`) is getting ignored and default view is rendered. In order to apply customization to list view with a custom style you could consider DOM manipulation as demonstrated below

> Note: to inject the customizations `Script Editor`/`Content Editor` web
>   parts could be utilized

**Example**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style type="text/css">

.in.collapse+a.btn.showdetails:before
{
    content:'Hide details «';
}
.collapse+a.btn.showdetails:before
{
    content:'Show details »';
}

  </style>

<script>

$(function(){

$.each($("td.ms-formbody"),function(i){
    var headline = $(this).text().substring(0,200);
    var template = String.format('<div class="span collapse-group">{0}' + 
           '<p class="collapse" id="viewdetails{2}">{1}</p>' +
           '<a class="btn showdetails" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#viewdetails{2}"></a>' +
        '</div>',headline,$(this).text(),i);
    $(this).html(template);    
});


});

</script>
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Thank you Vadim!! I will give this is a try. Is there a way to isolate this to just one list view on the page. Should I use #WebPartTitleWPQ3 or the id? Also is there to specify which button class to use from bootstrap?

Comment: Sure! There is also `webpartid` attribute to identify the specific web part.

Comment: I gave it a try and it didn't work. I fixed the link to bootstrap js file. I am using SharePoint online if it helps. Alternatively, I looked at a solution you created a while ago that could also work. (https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115402/sharepoint-2013-add-read-more-link-in-announcement-web-part-each-list-items). However, it doesn't allow me to set the ID of the webpart or increase the number of characters to display. I'd still like the title, modified and body to show up.

Comment: @maelstromm, strange enough, it works for me, in fact the provided screenshot is taken from SharePoint Online site

Comment: I tried this again and still no luck. Is there any guidance on how to set up the view? All I am using is Title, Modified and Body in Newsletter layout. From inline source, I have td.ms-vb-tall as the container of the body.